# Interpolation search in java

Tags: java, algorithm, search

My task at the university was to implement the interpolation search by students book_mark_ID and students who has passed the military preparation (*military_prep_sign* == "yes"). 
So I have Student class  with neccessary information(*ame, surname, book_mark_ID, military_prep_sign*) and I have created an array of Student type in the SearchAlgorithms class. I used an ArrayList to add found students. And I outputted the lements of array in main class.
The problem is that I do not get any data when I try to output found elements.

Interpolation search method in the **SearchAlgorithms class:**

```
public ArrayList<Student> interpolation_Search(int toFind)
{
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    //Student st2 = new Student();
    int low = 0;
    int high = st.length - 1;
    int mid;

    while(st[low].get_BookMarkID() < toFind && st[high].get_BookMarkID() > toFind)
    {
        mid = low + ((toFind - st[low].get_BookMarkID()) * (high - low)/ 
                (st[high].get_BookMarkID() - st[low].get_BookMarkID()));

        if(st[mid].get_BookMarkID() < toFind)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if(st[mid].get_BookMarkID() > toFind)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
        {
            if(st[mid].get_MilitaryPrepSign().equals("yes"))
            {
                students.add(st[mid]);
                mid++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(st[low].get_BookMarkID() == toFind)
    {
        if(st[low].get_MilitaryPrepSign().equals("yes"))
            students.add(st[low]);
    }

    else if(st[high].get_BookMarkID() == toFind)
    {
        if(st[high].get_MilitaryPrepSign().equals("yes"))
            students.add(st[high]);
    }

    return students;
}
```

**Main class:**

```
SearchAlgorithms new_search = new SearchAlgorithms(size);
    new_search.add(st);
    new_search.add(st1);
    new_search.add(st2);
    new_search.add(st3);
    new_search.add(st4);
    new_search.add(st5);

    new_search.display_Sort();
    new_search.insertionSort(0, 5);

    System.out.println("____________________");
    new_search.display_Sort();

    ArrayList<Student> students1 = new_search.interpolation_Search(532);
    System.out.println("\nFound student");
    for(Student student: students1)
    {
        System.out.println(student);
    }
```

Comment: I dont see "st" got passed into your method. Unless st is static....which i doubt it is

Comment: It is a field of class SearchAlgorithms.

Comment: do a system.out.println(st.size()) in your interpolation_Search function and run your program what did you see.

Comment: I would try using a debugger, and inserting a breakpoint at the beginning of your search method.

Comment: Based on your code, I think there is a chance multiple students can be assigned same bookMarkID?

Comment: Yes, I did not put any constraints on bookMarkID value for every student.

Comment: I assumed that your list already sorted by bookmarkID. Just set mid = (low + high)/2.

Comment: If students can have same bookmark, when st[mid].getBookmarkID() == toFind, you need to check vicinity of mid element